# Force rmarkdown::render() to fail on error

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a large rmarkdown file that gets rendered using the `rmarkdown::render()`-function inside of an Rscript file. Now I try to debug it, but I am unable to see error messages in the console output and it takes a long time to render everything.

Is there a way to force `rmarkdown::render()` to stop after the first error and output it to the terminal?

Comment: What you want is already the default behaviour of ‘rmarkdown’/‘knitr’: as soon as it encounters an error it stops execution and prints the error to stderr, unless you somehow suppress or handle that error yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats helps because now I only have to figure out where this behaviour was disabled.